eBay catalog API call results in HTTP status code '403 - Forbidden'
I'm getting HTTP status code 403-Forbidden when I'm trying to use eBay catalog API sample request from https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/commerce/catalog/resources/product_summary/methods/search.
It looks like OAuth scope https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/sell.inventory is missing for my app. But I can't find any information how to get this OAuth scope added.
For eBay API OAuth authorization I'm using eBay OAuth C# Client and it works well, I suppose, because I'm getting correct access token.
The C# sample code to get the product information, which returns 403-Forbidden, is as the following:

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");
        var testSearchUrl = "https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/commerce/catalog/v1_beta/product_summary/search?q=drone&limit=3";
        var result = client.GetAsync(testSearchUrl).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        System.Console.WriteLine($"{(int)result.StatusCode}-{result.StatusCode}");
    }

